# How can retrieve a user custom field instead of the default WooCommerce order field?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, custom-fields

can you tell me how I can retrieve a user custom field instead of the default WooCommerce order field?

In my particular case (I'm trying to customize a plugin which is a simple checkout iframe), I can simply summarize the case with sharing related line:

```
$user_phone         = substr($order->billing_phone, 0, 20);
```

This code successfully retrieves the WC billing_phone value and sends it to the payment gateway. But we needed to change it. We need to use a user custom field value instead of billing_phone.

So I modified it with:

```
$user_field_data = wpuef_get_field('c221', $order->get_customer_id());
$user_field_value = $user_field_data['value'];
$user_phone = substr($user_field_value, 0 ,20);
```

But it didn't work that I expected (unable to retrieve)

You can also want to review the whole file via https://codeshare.io/adLEAg
(you can find the by tries around line 284)

Thanks.

Edit:
user-extra-fields is coming from [User Extra Fields](https://codecanyon.net/item/user-extra-fields/12949844) plugin.

Comment: What is `wpuef_get_field`? What does it return? Also, when you say it doesn't work as expected, what did you expect and what did it return?

Comment: Looking at that code share you've got `return $user_id;` on line 290.  anything after that in your `generate_paytrcheckout_form()` function isn't going to run.

Comment: @mrben522 yes that's correct, the thing should happen in generate_paytrcheckout_form(). So my customization here(line 284) under a comment "# fix with a dynamic value"

Comment: @ChrisHaas It returns empty. I expected to retrieve that particular (order owner) customer's meta_value which belongs to the custom field has an ID c221